# Is it possible to run a specific bookmarklet in Chrome with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bookmarklet

It would make it much easier to share my JS script with folks if they didn't have to install a plugin.

On safari it's possible to use Cmd+number (I think) to directly load the n-th bookmark from the bookmark bar.

I need to run a JS script in my client when I am in a child-window (as that's where the webapp lives) and am finding it impossible to do from Chrome because you cannot bring up the bookmarks bar inside of a child window.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround which does work for my company's site is to just drag the URL over to an ungimped Chrome window, which sees it loading up just fine in there and I can then run my bookmarks freely.

Answer (score 0):

> **[SiteLauncher](https://www.donesmart.com/sitelauncher/chrome/)** is a free extension for Google Chrome that gives you
>   fast, tidy and beautiful single tap access to your favorite sites.
>
> - Set shortcuts to all your favorite sites and web-apps **any place that
>     has a URL**
> - Open shortcuts by keyboard, mouse or touch
>
> The Shortcut Manager makes it easy to add, edit and remove shortcuts.
>   **Each shortcut can point to any site, web-app, webpage you wish—if it
>   has a URL you can make a shortcut to it.** Option to set a keyboard
>   letter to each shortcut gives you super-fast keyboard navigation from
>   the Launcher—you don't even need to hit Enter!

I am **in absolutely no way** related to the software.